# natural selection keybindings for fish shell

Tags: fish

I am working on some natural selection keybindings.

For, <kbd>Delete</kbd> we know that it remove one char from the cursor, but if there is a selection then it removes the whole selection.

So, earlier my keybinding was `bind -k dc delete-char`. Now i am working on a function to solve this problem. My new keybinding is `bind -k dc selection_aware_delete`.

```
function selection_aware_backspace

    set -l cmdline
    if isatty stdin
        set cmdline (commandline --current-selection | string collect)
    end
    
    # if has selection then delete the whole selection else backward-delete-char

    if test -n "$cmdline"

    else
        commandline -f backward-delete-char
        return
    end

end
```

I have reached a point where i can identify if there is a selection. I can also remove char if there is no selection. I am not understanding how to delete selected text (The line after `if test -n "$cmdline"` and before `else`).

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in key binding for deleting the selection, named `kill-selection`. So `commandline -f kill-selection` will delete the selection.

You can get the list of bindings via `bind --function-names`, or via the [bind docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/bind.html).

Comment: Just curious for other bindings, if i use, `set start(commandline --selection-start)` and `set end(commandline --selection-end)`, it gives two points, suppose 0 and 10. How can I remove 0 to 10th character from a string using fish?

Comment: Probably the simplest is to use `string sub` to print the parts before and after the selection, e.g. `begin; string sub --end (commandline --selection-start); string sub --start (commandline --selection-end); end | string collect`.

Comment: Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/q/76400664/1772898